# Save data in a SQLite database with the original format and view those data again with that form format

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I need to save an invoice data and then need to preview that invoice as it is. It means I need to view that saved invoice data with that invoice format. Not only the values but also need to view the format as it is . Is this possible in android studio to do ? Highly appreciate your help...

This is my XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!--This is the customer name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invoTxt1"
            android:layout_width="142dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Billed To : "
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFB3BDBF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/invoTxt4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/invoTxt4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/SplitLine_hor1" />

    <!--Invoice Number this shoul be auto increased-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invoTxt4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Invoice No: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFB3BDBF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2x"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView18" />


        <!--Data of Issue-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:onClick="setDate"
            android:text="Date of Issue"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/invoTxt1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/invoTxt4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/invoTxt4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/date_selected"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/date" />


        <!--Invoice total amount-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invoTotal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Line Total:"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FF067591"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editSubTotal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editSubTotal"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editSubTotal" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
            android:background="#0095b6" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
            android:text="@string/date_selected"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/invoTxt1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/invoTxt1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <!--Edit subtotal-->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSubTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/invoiceDis"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editInvoiceDis"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editInvoiceDis" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sub Total"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editSubTotal"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/invoTotal"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/invoTotal"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invoiceDis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Invoice Discount (%)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editInvoiceDis"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/invoiceDisT"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/invoiceDisT" />

    <!--Enter Invoice Discount-->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editInvoiceDis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
            android:layout_marginTop="163dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textGetAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="                                                 "
                android:layout_below="@+id/invoTxt1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/invoTxt1"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/invoTxt1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABCDE Company Private Limited"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <!--after click this button user redirect to another activity and it open a list item description-->    
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add a Line"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshapes"
                android:layout_below="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/SplitLine_hor1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/invoiceDisT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:layout_below="@+id/invoiceDis"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subTotal"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/subTotal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSubTNDiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/invoiceDisT"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<!--Save invoice-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textGetAddress"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textGetAddress" />

  <!--View Listview of saved invoices by clicking this button-->  
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2x"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/invoTxt4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/invoTxt4"
                android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:text="View" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible but there are some things you should clear first. How will you enter invoice data(images or text)? How will you want to save data? What have you done till now? Have you created any layout you're going to use? Will you use multiple edittexts?

Comment: Also, providing nothing causes the downvotes which you have 4 till now.

Comment: I have an invoice form, once this invoice form is opened user can enter data. After that user can save click a save button. Then need to view those invoice created users' name as a listview. Once we click on a listview item  the invoice need to open as it is format, not only the data but with the format. If it is possible please help me, I am quite new to android

Comment: You can save details in sql with multiple columns as per your need and create a list view showing titles of invoices and clicking that list item opens the same invoice form you have but with textviews instead of edittexts filled with your details from the database. Share your XML.

Comment: How to add my XML code to here

Comment: Edit the question, copy your xml and paste it in the question and then select whatever you will paste and press ctrl+k to set code format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer as I'm not going to give you the prewritten code for a copy/paste.
 You should figure it out on your own but I'll give you an overview of what you have to do.**

1. Search how to create SQL database and learn it through youtube tutorials. [Some videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sql%20tutorials%20for%20android&page=&utm_source=opensearch).
2. Learn SQL (some basics) to understand what are columns and rows and
   how to use them for storing data. [See here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/).
3. This way you'll learn how to store database and retrieve some data from it.
4. After learning(some basics, just 1-2 days), you'll know how to insert data into listviews using adapters and in textviews.

Just an example - suppose you've populated the listview using your SQL database and you click on a list item named "Kash", then you can transition to a new activity which will have the same layout of current activity( the layout you've posted here, just change every `edittext` to `textview`) and set text to every textview by using this example -

- you should execute this raw query for every textview.
        suppose you want to take the name from the database where invoice name = "kash" then `"select Name from table_name where invoice_name = "Kash";"`. Save the selected text to a string(ex -namestring) value or cursor and show this in textview of name as `textviewName.setText(namestring);`
- Or you can use the same query for every textview as 
   create an if condition where every condition compares to a textview and set a separate columnName for every separate textview.
  then the query can be `"select "+ columnName +" from tableName where invoice_name = "+ listitemClicked;"` and set this retrieved value to every respective textview.

This way you'll  have what you need. But as No-one on StackOverflow wants to serve you the code for no efforts or less efforts at all.

**Remember**, what you want is not a hard thing but you should do it on your own.
 
**This information is more than enough to proceed**.
I could've downvoted you and left but downvoting isn't the solution.

Comment: thank you for your help..., This help me a lot and I think Now I can do this, Thanks again:)

Comment: No problem at all.